# New line \n is replaced with \#012

Tags: bash, rsync

I have created a small alias function to sync my scripts.

It worked fine until last week but now in my rsync command it doesn't do the newlines anymore. They are replaced by `\#012`

```
rsync: failed to open exclude file .DS_Store\#012GitHub_public/\#012Scrips....
```

If I do `echo $exclude_files` all is fine, I have every exclude fine in each line

```
.DS_Store
GitHub_public/
Scripts/.DS_Store
```

I have the same behaviour on both my computers and I am unable to find out where it comes from. I have removed my .zshrc if it was an extension that created the bug but no change.

```bash
function rsyncScripts() {

    computer_name=$(scutil --get ComputerName | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
    SRC="$HOME/Developer"
    exclude_files=$(git -C $SRC ls-files --exclude-standard -oi --directory)

    if ! [[ "${computer_name}" =~ "yyyyyy" ]]; then
        DEST="$HOME/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-xxxxx@gmail.com/Mon Drive/Developer/pro"
    else
        DEST="$HOME/Library/CloudStorage/GoogleDrive-xxxxx@gmail.com/Mon Drive/Developer/perso"
    fi

    rsync -azP --exclude-from="$exclude_files" "$SRC" "$DEST"

}
```

Comment: Also, `man rsync` says `--exclude-from=FILE      read exclude patterns from FILE` but you pass a list of pattern/names instead.